Ability to create custom y-axis labels in Highchart
I am trying to create a Highcharts column chart, and it will be displaying percentages of a specific task completed. The criteria this task is asking for a y-axis label of the following:
from bottom to top:
0%
15%
30%
45%
60%
75%
100%
So basically it 'almost' wants to be displayed with a tick value of 15, with the exception of the last number being 100. If I implement it with a tick of 15, it ends with 75, 90, 105, as expected.
I have looked at how to create custom labels with the 'this.value', but that is always a multiple of ten if I do not specify tick value(s). So far I have not been able to find anything that would allow me to create these custom labels with the sequence desired.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have tried looking at the Highcharts documentation, and looking at the various JSFiddle examples, but so far nothing has been able to produce that I am looking for.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

So literally a few minutes after I posted, I found the answer in another older post.
Then answer was using tickPositions option:
tickPositions: [0, 15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 100]
